# Vagrant and Rails server: cannot connect to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, localhost

I'm trying to run a Rails app from my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit virtual machine on Vagrant. Either running `rails server` or `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` works, but in both cases when I try to reach `localhost:3000` or `0.0.0.0:3000` from my local Windows 10 machine, it says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I also put this line in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

which should theoretically allow port forwarding on 3000, but when I run `netstat -ntlp` I get:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50891           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::36063                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

so somehow my Vagrant machine is not listening to port 3000 anyway.

I also tried to `vagrant reload`, to no avail.
Rails version is 5.0.1.

Where am I failing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The line in the Vagrantfile must be:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

so with a colon instead of quotes.